# Find HTML tag string in text using applescript and return value true or false

Tags: html, find, applescript, boolean, delimiter

I'm looking for an applescript routine or subroutine to find this HTML tag string:

`<td width="487">`

in this HTML code:

```
                <h1><span id="profile-name-94461" >Jan Schlatter</span></h1>



            </span>

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="profile-table">
                                    <tr>
                    <th width="163" scope="col">Introduction</th>
                    <td width="487">Education :
<br />Management and support on responsibilities in finances and accounting.</td>
                </tr>
                                                        <tr>
                    <th>Role</th>
                    <td>
                    <p>Portfolio Management</p><p>Senior Management</p>                     </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>  
                    <th>Organisation Type</th>
                    <td>
                    <p>Family Office</p>                        </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <td><a href="mailto:jan.schlatter@bohnetschlatter.ch" title="jan.schlatter@bohnetschlatter.ch" >jan.schlatter@bohnetschlatter.ch</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Website</th>
                    <td><a href="http://bohnetschlatter.ch" target="_new" title="http://bohnetschlatter.ch" >http://bohnetschlatter.ch</a></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Phone</th>
                    <td>+41 41 727 61 61</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Fax</th>
                    <td>+41 41 727 61 62</td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Mailing Address</th>
                    <td>Gartenstrasse 2<br>Postfach 42</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <td>Zurich</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>State</th>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Country</th>
                    <td>Switzerland</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th class="lastrow" >Zip/ Postal Code</th>
                    <td class="lastrow" >6301</td>
                </tr>
        </table>
```

Because the HTML tag is not always in every HTML file that I would like to process, I would like it to return a boolean value to be used in an if, then, else statement, to then complete an action if the value returns "true".

The applescript that I've started with is

```
set intoTag to "<td width=" & quote & "487" & quote & ">"
   on stripLastWordBeforeLogoEndTag(theText)
  set text item delimiters to introTag
  set a to text items of theText
  set b to item 1 of a
  set text item delimiters to space
  set item 1 of a to (text items 1 thru -2 of b) as text
  set text item delimiters to "</Logo>"
  set fixedText to a as text
  set text item delimiters to ""
return fixedText

if infoTag = fixedText then set bool to true
else set bool to false
end if

if true then (do action[[set extractText_INTRODUCTION to extractBetween(extractText, "<td width=" & quote & "487" & quote & ">", "</td>")]])
else (do not do action)
end if
```

I would rather **not** use a shell script because I have almost no knowledge in how to edit shell scripts. Text delimiters would be the best solution in my point of view, although any answers are welcome. Thanks

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want to use a text editor for this?

Comment: I've already created a long applescript to parse HTML files using delimiters. My goal is to parse more than 1800 HTML files. The output should be 1800 csv files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest is to use `is in`

```
set introTag to "<td width=\"487\">"
set existTag to introTag is in theText
if existTag then
    -- true
else
    -- false
end if
```

Comment: Good answer. Could be shortened slightly by merging lines 2 and 3 into `if (introTag is in theText) then`, though.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a shell script, you could use the **offset** command from Standard Additions, which will search for one piece of text inside another.  If the text is not found, the result will be 0, which can be used in your if statement, for example:

```
set theText to "...<table width=\"100%\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" id=\"profile-table\">
                                    <tr>
                    <th width=\"163\" scope=\"col\">Introduction</th>
                    <td width=\"487\">Education :..."

set here to offset of "<td width=\"487\">" in theText
if here is not 0 then
    log "text found at " & here -- do your stuff
end if
```